# What's the best way to represent ctrl+= in a code snippet?

Tags: discussion

Let's say I use ctrl+= (free form input) in an answer to get an `Entity` or whatever. What's the best way to add that in a code block?

Has this issue come up since V10 has been released?

My only thoughts are to use a screenshot, or `ctrl+=["query"]` but these don't seem like the optimal solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Personally I would use the entity directly.  Since the input method is not part of the code, I'd mention it separately.  For example:

---

```
school = Entity["University", "UniversityOfIllinoisAtUrbanaChampaign145637"]
GeoNearest["City", school]
(* {Entity["City", {"Champaign", "Illinois", "UnitedStates"}]} *)
```

(You can enter `school` as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> `uiuc`)